# Error message upon installing wdm gem

Tags: ruby, rubygems, jekyll

I followed this guide here on installing jekyll: labs.sverrirs.com/jekyll/5-wdm-gem.html

But I can't seem to install wdm. I installed Ruby-devkit, and ruby2.3 64bit. However, when I try to type in gem install wdm, it displays:

To see why this extension failed to compile, please check the mkmf.log which can
 be found here:

```
 C:/Ruby23-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.3.0/extensions/x64-mingw32/2.3.0/wdm-0.1.1/mkmf.
log

extconf failed, exit code 1

Gem files will remain installed in C:/Ruby23-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.3.0/gems/wdm-0.
1.1 for inspection.
Results logged to C:/Ruby23-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.3.0/extensions/x64-mingw32/2.3.0
/wdm-0.1.1/gem_make.out
```

The mkmf file says this:

```
"x86_64-w64-mingw32-gcc -o conftest.exe -IC:/Ruby23-x64/include/ruby-2.3.0/x64-mingw32 -IC:/Ruby23-x64/include/ruby-2.3.0/ruby/backward -IC:/Ruby23-x64/include/ruby-2.3.0 -I. -DFD_SETSIZE=2048 -D_WIN32_WINNT=0x0501 -D__MINGW_USE_VC2005_COMPAT -D_FILE_OFFSET_BITS=64   -O3 -fno-omit-frame-pointer -fno-fast-math -g -Wall -Wextra -Wno-unused-parameter -Wno-parentheses -Wno-long-long -Wno-missing-field-initializers -Wunused-variable -Wpointer-arith -Wwrite-strings -Wdeclaration-after-statement -Wimplicit-function-declaration -Wdeprecated-declarations -Wno-packed-bitfield-compat conftest.c  -L. -LC:/Ruby23-x64/lib -L.      -lx64-msvcrt-ruby230  -lshell32 -lws2_32 -liphlpapi -limagehlp -lshlwapi  "
checked program was:
/* begin */
1: #include "ruby.h"
2: 
3: #include <winsock2.h>
4: #include <windows.h>
5: int main(int argc, char **argv)
6: {
7:   return 0;
8: }
/* end */
```

I have no idea what this means, what to do?

The gem file:

```
    current directory: C:/Ruby23-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.3.0/gems/wdm-0.1.1/ext/wdm
C:/Ruby23-x64/bin/ruby.exe -r ./siteconf20161205-2832-xgt8yg.rb extconf.rb
checking for main() in -lkernel32... *** extconf.rb failed ***
Could not create Makefile due to some reason, probably lack of necessary
libraries and/or headers.  Check the mkmf.log file for more details.  You may
need configuration options.

Provided configuration options:
    --with-opt-dir
    --without-opt-dir
    --with-opt-include
    --without-opt-include=${opt-dir}/include
    --with-opt-lib
    --without-opt-lib=${opt-dir}/lib
    --with-make-prog
    --without-make-prog
    --srcdir=.
    --curdir
    --ruby=C:/Ruby23-x64/bin/$(RUBY_BASE_NAME)
    --with-kernel32lib
    --without-kernel32lib
C:/Ruby23-x64/lib/ruby/2.3.0/mkmf.rb:456:in `try_do': The compiler failed to generate an executable file. (RuntimeError)
You have to install development tools first.
    from C:/Ruby23-x64/lib/ruby/2.3.0/mkmf.rb:541:in `try_link0'
    from C:/Ruby23-x64/lib/ruby/2.3.0/mkmf.rb:556:in `try_link'
    from C:/Ruby23-x64/lib/ruby/2.3.0/mkmf.rb:765:in `try_func'
    from C:/Ruby23-x64/lib/ruby/2.3.0/mkmf.rb:997:in `block in have_library'
    from C:/Ruby23-x64/lib/ruby/2.3.0/mkmf.rb:942:in `block in checking_for'
    from C:/Ruby23-x64/lib/ruby/2.3.0/mkmf.rb:350:in `block (2 levels) in postpone'
    from C:/Ruby23-x64/lib/ruby/2.3.0/mkmf.rb:320:in `open'
    from C:/Ruby23-x64/lib/ruby/2.3.0/mkmf.rb:350:in `block in postpone'
    from C:/Ruby23-x64/lib/ruby/2.3.0/mkmf.rb:320:in `open'
    from C:/Ruby23-x64/lib/ruby/2.3.0/mkmf.rb:346:in `postpone'
    from C:/Ruby23-x64/lib/ruby/2.3.0/mkmf.rb:941:in `checking_for'
    from C:/Ruby23-x64/lib/ruby/2.3.0/mkmf.rb:992:in `have_library'
    from extconf.rb:19:in `<main>'

To see why this extension failed to compile, please check the mkmf.log which can be found here:

  C:/Ruby23-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.3.0/extensions/x64-mingw32/2.3.0/wdm-0.1.1/mkmf.log

extconf failed, exit code 1
```

Comment: FWIW: http://rubyinstaller.org/downloads/ states "The 64-bit versions of Ruby are relatively new on the Windows area and not all the packages have been updated to be compatible with it. To use this version you will require some knowledge about compilers and solving dependency issues, which might be too complicated if you just want to play with the language."  You may want to go the 32-bit route on Windows.  YMMV.

Comment: Does not seem to be a 64bit issue, works fine for me on win10x64 running ruby-x64

Answer (score 0):

Could you please paste the content of the mkmf.log file and gem_make.out?

I just tried to install the gem on a Win10 running Ruby 64bit and this does not seem to be an issue.

Edit: OK, the error states, that your devkit is not installed correctly. Did you follow the instructions on ruby's website and install the correct version for your ruby version?